# hbase value filter performance

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hbase

how to search the specified value in hbase quickly?

I tried with below filter along with skipfilter but performance is poor and got **timeout/callout exception**, I have 5 000 000 000 records.

I am unable to search quickly.

```
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("qualifier"),CompareOp.EQUAL,Bytes.toBytes("1234"));

ValueFilter filter =  new ValueFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL,Bytes.toBytes("1234"));
```

To fetch all 1234 value available in all records.

Is there any way to improve performance on filters?

Answer (score 0):

Not really if you look for a specific column value that is not part of the rowkey, HBase needs to perform a full table scan, thus it is slower than searching by rowkey.